# Grid SharedSizeGroup is not working across the whole view

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a simple application where I want all the buttons in the View be of same size. The problem with this code is, all the buttons in Grid Row 0 are of same width but the buttons in Grid Row 2 are not the same. Please help.

I want the buttons in Grid Row 2 to be of the same width as Grid Row 0. 
(Is it possible to do it with a Grid like this. Please don't tell me a Uniform Grid. I know it works with UniformGrid and I also don't want to do Binding ElementName=so and so,Path=ActualWidth)

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" x:Name="InstrumentOperationsPanel" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="PrimeButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="ABCD"/>
            <Button x:Name="FlushButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="ABCDEFGHIJKL"/>
            <Button Content="ABCD" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="PrimeFlush3TimesButton" Grid.Column="3" Content="ABCD"/>

        </Grid>
        <Separator Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </Separator>

        <Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" x:Name="BuiltInUserActionPanelForQX200" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="DRDiagnosticsButton" Grid.Column="0"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QXFieldAgentButton" Grid.Column="1"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QX200MTSButton" Grid.Column="2"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QX200MTSDetectorButton" Grid.Column="3"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need couple of changes.

a) In your main Grid,

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

b) In InstrumentOperationsPanel, Grid, Remove Grid.IsSharedSizeScope

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="InstrumentOperationsPanel">
```

c) In BuiltInUserActionPanelForQX200 Grid, Remove Grid.IsSharedSizeScope

```
<Grid  x:Name="BuiltInUserActionPanelForQX200" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```

Your entire Xaml Would not look like

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="InstrumentOperationsPanel">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="PrimeButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="ABCD"/>
            <Button x:Name="FlushButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="ABCDEFGHIJKL"/>
            <Button Content="ABCD" Grid.Column="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="PrimeFlush3TimesButton" Grid.Column="3" Content="ABCD"/>

        </Grid>
        <Separator Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </Separator>

        <Grid  x:Name="BuiltInUserActionPanelForQX200" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="DRDiagnosticsButton" Grid.Column="0"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QXFieldAgentButton" Grid.Column="1"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QX200MTSButton" Grid.Column="2"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="QX200MTSDetectorButton" Grid.Column="3"
                Content="ABCD"></Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should only set ISSharedSizeScope=True on the outermost grid.

Remove Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" from the inner grids (InstrumentOperationsPanel and BuiltInUserActionPanelForQX200)